# unable to transform Special Characters in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="line1">
<body><xsl:value-of select="line2[@NAME='data']"/></body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<line1>
  <line2 name="data"><!CDATA[地址：北京经济技术开发区分新<span lang="ZH-CN" style="font-family:SimSun">号诺基亚大厦</span>]</line2>
</line1>
```

I have problems in transforming the data in XML file. When I tried to generate output XML, error: Invalid XML characters is shown. Can Anyone Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The CDATA section in your XML instance is not correct. It's missing an opening bracket before `CDATA`, a closing bracket and a closing angle bracket. It should have the form: `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`.

Here is the corrected form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<line1>
    <line2 name="data"><![CDATA[地址：北京经济技术开发区分新<span lang="ZH-CN" style="font-family:SimSun">号诺基亚大厦</span>]]></line2>
</line1>
```

Also, your XSLT will not find the `name` attribute since you are looking for `NAME` (case matters). Change it to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="line2[@name='data']"/>
```

This is the result using Saxon-EE 9.5.1.3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>地址：北京经济技术开发区分新&lt;span lang="ZH-CN" style="font-family:SimSun"&gt;号诺基亚大厦&lt;/span&gt;</body>
```

2) If you want to preserve the `CDATA` section in the result, then you add `cdata-section-elements="body"` to your `output`:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="body"/>
```

And your result will be:

```
<body><![CDATA[地址：北京经济技术开发区分新<span lang="ZH-CN" style="font-family:SimSun">号诺基亚大厦</span>]]></body>
```

3) But it seems you are trying to build a XML and want the `<span>` element unescaped. In that case you should add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to the `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="line2[@name='data']"/>
```

(and remove the `cdata-section-elements="body"` from `output` in case you added one) then your result will be:

```
<body>地址：北京经济技术开发区分新<span lang="ZH-CN" style="font-family:SimSun">号诺基亚大厦</span></body>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks A lot for the answer...I still get the same error after changing accordingly...Can you suggest me in this

Comment: I just tested your code. I'll add the results above. If you still have problems it may be an encoding problem not related to XSL or XML (check if you are saving your file in UTF-8, if you are using a BOM header, etc.)

Comment: Is there any possibility to support all unicode characters in xml transformation to another xml using xslt. I am facing issues with few other unicode or foreign characters in CDATA field of XML. Can you Please help in this.